DPDK application test using virtual network device
I have Linux virtual machine with one NIC. Accordingly I have only one network interface.
I want to test my DPDK app on virtual device using --vdev net_tap0 option. I run my application, and I see using ifconfig this interface was successfully created.
Then I assign an IP address to interface and try to ping. But RX and TX packets count doesn't increase in ifconfig output. IP is assigned to the same subnet as the IP of the physical interface.
How can I make it so that I can send myself network packets via the specified IP of the virtual network interface?
What settings should be specified when running DPDK application so that the interface becomes accessible?
What other methods of testing DPDK applications?
P.S.
Also you can take into account that my application should not respond in TX queue if it matters.
